# Ninject - Injecting a dependency into a namespace

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-2

I'm attempting to conditionally bind a dependency when it's injected into a certain namespace.  I found a Ninject [article](https://lukewickstead.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/howto-ninject-part-2-advanced-features) on conditional binding where it says the following:

> We can also provide conditional logic by providing a delegate. In this case are asking the class its name and namespace.
>
> Bind().To().When(request => request.Target.Member.Name.StartsWith("ClassName"));
>   Bind().To().When(request => request.Target.Type.Namespace.StartsWith("NameSpace.ClassName"));

So I've tried to implement this as follows:

```
Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod(x => new Logger("commissionServiceLogger")).When(x => x.Target.Type.Namespace.StartsWith("My.App.CommissionService"));
```

I'm getting a null reference exception, though:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x.Target.Type` will give you the dependency that you are trying to resolve. In your case, this is `ILogger`.

I am guessing that you mean to base the logic on the type of object in which `ILogger` is to be injected. In this case, you need to use `x.ParentContext.Plan.Type` like this:

```
Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod(x => new Logger("commissionServiceLogger")).When(x =>
{
    return x.ParentContext != null &&
         x.ParentContext.Plan
         .Type.Namespace
         .StartsWith("My.App.CommissionService");
});
```

`ParentContext` would be `null` in the case where you try to resolve `ILogger` directly.